# $http error Function not showing error message

Tags: ajax, angularjs, spring-mvc, exception

I have to give user a proper message while ajax call got fail

My Ajax call is as follows:

```
$http({
                method:'PUT',
                url:"/myapp/web/update",
                crossDomain:true,               
                data:dataobj,
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                }
            }).success(function (data) {                
                console.log("error"+JSON.stringify(data));
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("error"+JSON.stringify(data));
            });
```

from the backed i have used Spring MVC 4 as restfull api. From that i am validating the data and send response accordingly. If something went wrong in validation i throw custom exceptions.

Now if i throw just exception it got cached in **Ajax success function** but i want it to have to catch this in error function. for this i add following line of code :

```
  response.sendError(500);
```

Now it got cached in **error function** as expected but i cant find JSON error message with it. Can anybody tell where i went wrong in the code.

Edit:

Following is the Code where i am responding with error message

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController{

@ExceptionHandler(EmployeeNotFoundException.class)
public @ResponseBody ExceptionJSONInfo handleEmployeeNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){

    ExceptionJSONInfo response = new ExceptionJSONInfo();
    response.setUrl(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    response.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    response.sendError(500);
    return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code of your api method

Comment: @AjinderSingh i have added the code.

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: @NikolayRusev AngularJS v1.3.17

Comment: do you have defined custom http interceptor? if yes. please add the code to your question

Comment: No, There no custom http interceptor.